# Why are singletons terminal objects in Set when there can be morphisms between different singletons?

Tags: category-theory

I'm trying to learn category theory and I have a doubt with the Set category.
According to Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_of_sets empty sets are the initial objects, which have morphisms to categories each one containing a set.

It says that singletons are terminal objects but as far as I understand, it's possible to have a morphism from a singleton to another singleton. Say `A={e1}` and `B={e2}` are singletons, one could have the morphism `<A, f = subset of AxB, B> = <{e1}, {(e1, e2)}, {e2}>` which should generate an arrow from `{e1}` to `{e2}`, making `{e1}` non-terminal.

What am I assuming wrong? it it possible that `f` is instead of a subset of `AxB`, is a strict subset?

Comment: Terminal doesn't mean there are no morphisms from it. It means that there is only one morphism to it from any given object. "$T$ is [terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_and_terminal_objects) if for every object $X$ in $\mathbf C$ there exists a single morphism $X → T$."

Comment: Yes, I misunderstood what a terminal object is.